# Editor de Texto para Javascript sin formato para Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, formato, edittext, texto

Tengo un problema que me trae de cabeza. Recientemente instalé en mi equipo el eclipse:

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers
Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que cualquier tipo de fichero (.java, .xml, .css) se ve con el formato correcto (es decir, con los colores según sean funciones, variables, etc), excepto para los .js:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado varias cosas, incluso añadir plugins para que aparezca, e incluso he configurado las preferencias del editor.

Tengo también instalado Eclipse Web Tools:

[image]

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: ¿Ya instalaste las herramientas para Web y Javascript en Eclipse?

Comment: ¿A qué herramientas te refieres exactamente?

Comment: A estas: [Eclipse Web Tools](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools). Saludos

Comment: Eso ya lo tenía instalado. He editado la publicación para indicarlo, por si sirve de ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Hola que tal la solución que me sirvió a mi fue la siguiente:
Ve a Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations

En la sección de File Types verifica que este la extensión "*.js", si no lo esta, la agregas presionando el boton Add.
[image: Img1]

Se agrega de la siguiente manera, después en Ok.
[image: Img2]

En la sección Associated editors seleccionas la opción Generic Text Editor, le das a default, por ultimo Aply and Close, quedándote de la siguiente forma.
[image: Img3]

Espero te haya servido, saludos cordiales.